# Login failing using Safari browser

Tags: button, browser, authentication, safari

I have an application developed on asp.net and vb.net.
The problem which I am facing here is that when I try to login to the application using Safari Browser in windows xp environment the textbox where I gave the UserId is getting empty and login is not happening.
The application is hosted in remote server over IIS
However this issue is not happening when I run the application on my local.
and this issue I am facing while using Safari browser only.

Comment: Which autentication method are you using?

Comment: its Forms authentication..

Comment: Here adding to the above question I have tried splitting the viewstate size using the maxPageStateFieldLength="500"> in web.config as a possible solution but the issue still persists.
Can someone let me know whether cache settings of the safari browsers has to do anything with this.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me out on this issue Thanks